# != not working in while loop, causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

```
 Name=input("Enter name")
 Age=int(input("Enter Age"))
 Gender=input("Enter Gender")
 while Gender!="M"or Gender!="F"or Gender!="T":
  print("try again")
  Gender=input("Enter Gender")
 print(Name,Age,Gender)
```

the above code causes an infinite loop.

Comment: What language is this? Please add it to the list of tags. Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Your conditon is not appropriate as the output you expect. It says that if any of these contains are there go in loop again. EXAMPLE: if gender== M then it still goes in loop as the other conditions are true that "M"!="F" AND "M"!="T"

Answer (score 0):

Well check your condition. It means

If Geneder is not M **or** Gender is not F **or** gender is not T
then keep looping

That means even if you input "M" it will go in the other condition because it is not "F". Basically the operator is not the problem - it's the condition. Gender will ALWAYS be different than one of these.

You can try to switch it to AND (do while none of these is true)

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comment your condition is not appropriate as per output you expect.

For that kind of output you need to change condition and that can be achieved with help of a list.
And there should be some input validation also in your code for int check for age.

You can use the code below

```
Name=input("Enter name")

#int validation check for Age variable START
inl=True
while(inl):
    try :
        Age=int(input("Enter Age"))
        inl=False
    except:
        print("Age must be a integer !")
#int validation check for Age variable END

Gender=input("Enter Gender")
a=["M","F","T"]

#condition change for Gender check
while Gender.upper() not in a:
    print("Input A valid Gender like 'M' or 'F' or 'T'")
    Gender=input("Enter Gender")

print(Name,Age,Gender)
```

This will solve out your problem.